# Matlab function for many branches

Tags: matlab

So I have created a script and I want to convert it to a function x(t) so I can use it for other instances. For example,I want to use the function so I can get x(2t) or x(-t).

My script is:

```
t = 0:0.01:8;
x = zeros(size(t));
cond1 = t>=0 & t<1;
cond2 = t>=1 & t<3;
x(cond1) = t(cond1);
x(cond2) = 1/2*(3 - 2*t(cond2));
plot (t,x), grid
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is you code in a function:

```
t = 0:0.01:8;

x = foo(2*t); % Call the function with 2*t
figure
plot (t,x), grid

x = foo(-t); % Call the function with -t
figure
plot (t,x), grid

% Function foo
function x = foo(t)
x = zeros(size(t));
cond1 = t>=0 & t<1;
cond2 = t>=1 & t<3;
x(cond1) = t(cond1);
x(cond2) = 1/2*(3 - 2*t(cond2));
end
```

Comment: problem is when you plot the x(-t) it shows a straight line(which is obviously wrong),and when you make x(2*t) it creates the wrong signal again.

Comment: @stef: It's the logic your code. Try `t = t*2` or `t = -t` it with your original code, you will get the same result.